# "Address already in use" on page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, web-applications, servlets

I have a web application which, among other things it does, listens on a socket for a connection for a message from a remote client. My problem arises when the user does a page refresh. After a page refresh, the application is getting reloaded and it's again trying to listen on the same port for which the there is an exception-"Address already in use."

Is there a way I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating Socket on same page. And when that page is refreshed the request for the socket creation is sent again for the same address and that address is already bound.

There are a couple of ways to resolve it. Easiest is to separate Socket creation from your page and handle the connection and refresh accordingly.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on what you mean by "separate socket creation from your page"? I actually have an ajax call on my main page. The ajax call is to a servlet which in turn instantiates a java class and calls its method for listening on socket, readign message and closing the connection.. This message is being returned in my ajax call and relaces the div item on my page....this ajax function is called for every certain time..

Comment: Please excuse me for delayed response. Well that servlet of your's that is handling Socket creation should check if socket if already there than it should close existing Socket and open new one...